# Convergence of $\sqrt[n]{s_n}$ given $s_ns_m \leq s_{n+m}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given $(s_n)_{n \geq 1}$, a sequence of positive integers and the inequality $s_ns_m \leq s_{n+m}$ for all integers $n, m$, how does one go about proving that the sequence $(\sqrt[n]{s_n})_{n \geq 1}$ converges?

It is quite easy to see that the sequence is monotone increasing, so all we need is an upper bound for all of its terms. I don't quite see how to do this, since the inequality only seems to give a lower bound..

Comment: Considering this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350699/if-x-mn-le-x-nx-m-then-lim-x-n-n-exists-and-is-equal-to-inf-x-n-n I think the inequality was reversed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sequence $s_n = 2^{n^2}$ and observe that
\begin{align}
s_ns_m = 2^{n^2+m^2} \leq 2^{(m+n)^2}= s_{n+m}
\end{align}
but we see that
\begin{align}
\sqrt[n]{s_n} = 2^n\rightarrow \infty.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample. There must have been a mistake in the book I'm reading.