# Sequence Limit Problem: If $0 \leq x_{m+n} \leq x_n + x_m$ then limit of $x_n/n$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If the sequence $\{x_n\}$ satisfies the property that $0 \leq x_{m+n} \leq x_n + x_m$ for all $n$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$ , show that the limit of the sequence $\left\{\frac{x_n}{n}\right\}_n$ exists. Provide an example of such a sequence.

I can show that it is bounded, but I don't know how to show that it is monotone increasing (I think it is monotone increasing, not sure).

Comment: This fact is often called *[Fekete's lemma](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Fekete+lemma%22)*, see, for example [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57455/existence-of-a-limit-associated-to-an-almost-subadditive-sequence/57493#57493).

Comment: [This post on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162848/regarding-sub-additive-sequences-and-feketes-lemma) says that it is not possible to show that every subadditive sequence is monotone.

Comment: See also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350699/if-x-mn-le-x-nx-m-then-lim-x-n-n-exists-and-is-equal-to-inf-x-n-n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's fix the number $p$ and write $n = pm + k$, where $0 \leq k < p$, then we have

\begin{align}
\frac{x_{pm+k}}{pm+k} &\leq \frac{x_{pm}}{pm+k} + \frac{x_k}{pm+k} \\
& \leq \frac{mx_p}{pm} + \frac{px_1}{pm}
\end{align}

when we send $m$ to infinity, we get $\limsup\frac{x_n}{n} \leq \frac{x_p}{p}$, since here $k $ can only vary finitely from 0 to $p-1$

Since $p$ is arbitrary, we can say that $\exists N_1$, such that for all $n \geq N_1$, $\frac{x_n}{n} \leq \frac{x_1}{1}$.

and $\exists N_2$, such that for all $n \geq N_2$, $\frac{x_n}{n} \leq \frac{x_{N_1}}{N_1}$

continue in this way, the sequence $\frac{x_{N_k}}{N_k}, k = 1,2,\cdots$ is decreasing and bounded for below by 0, so their limit exsits.

And the conclusion follows by $\limsup\frac{x_n}{n} \leq \frac{x_p}{p}$ for any $p$.

Or as Zarrax says in the comment, we can directly conclude by noting $\limsup\frac{x_n}{n} \leq \liminf\frac{x_p}{p}$

One example is to take $a_n = \sqrt{n}$

Comment: Aren't you already done once you know that $\limsup {a_n \over n} \leq {a_p \over p}$ for all $p$? Once you know that, you automatically have $\limsup {a_n \over n} \leq \liminf {a_p \over p}$ so the limit must exist.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, this makes the proof shorter, thanks

Comment: just wondering must the sequence be non-negative? From the proof, i think it doesn't really matter right? does it?

Comment: @user136266 if the sequence is not bounded from below, its limit can be $-\infty$, take $x_n = -n$ for example